# Как определить размер файла в программе на C?

Tags: c

Нужно выделить память, равную размеру файла в байтах, под массив байтов и затем считать файл в этот массив.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Нужно использовать функцию fstat.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    void *buffer = NULL;

    int descriptor = open("filename", O_RDONLY);

    if (descriptor != -1) {
        FILE *file = fdopen(descriptor, "rb");

        if (file) {
            struct stat statistics;

            if (fstat(descriptor, &statistics) != -1) {
                buffer = (char*)malloc(statistics.st_size);
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
        close(descriptor);
    }

    if (!buffer) {
        free(buffer);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**C, C++**

Или можно сделать [fseek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75yw9bf3.aspx) на конец файла. А затем [ftell](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ys3hc0b.aspx) для получения текущего положения курсора в файле.

PS: при этом нужно быть аккуратным с файлами, размер которых превышает макс. значение для типа long. В этом случае можно воспользоваться 64-битными версиями ф-ций.

PPS: для того, чтобы ftell вернул именно размер файла, нужно его открыть в бинарном режиме.

**C++ (w boost):**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
     std::cout << "Usage: tut1 path\n";
     return 1;
  }
  std::cout << argv[1] << " " << file_size(argv[1]) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, не стоит париться, а посмотреть в сторону [Memory Mapped Files](https://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/mmap.html) (POSIX) и [CreateFileMapping function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx) (WIN)